# How to call a script with unknown parameters

Tags: powershell

I have a script that calls other scripts that other people manage. It's essentially a CI/CD script that gives users the ability to tap into the pipeline.

The issue I'm running into now is that I would like this calling script to implement a couple new parameters. However, the old scripts don't always implement those parameters.

If I call their script that doesn't implement the parameters, I get an error "A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'newparameter'".

Is there a way to dynamically pass in a parameter so that it doesn't fail if the parameter doesn't exist? I don't mind if they don't implement it. It's a bonus parameter that they don't need to use.

Alternately, can I do something like a Get-Command for a custom .ps1 script, to get a list of accepted parameters? With that, I could confirm that a parameter is implemented before I pass it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might help you get started, you could use the [`Parser` Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.language.parser?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0)
 to get all functions and it's parameters from a script, this answer shows a minimal reproduction. I'll leave it to you to investigate further.

Given `myScript.ps1` that has these 3 functions:

```bash
function ExampleFunc {
    param([int] $param1 = 123, [string] $param2)
}

function ExampleFunc2 {
    param([object] $param3, [switch] $param4)
}

function ExampleFunc3 ($param5, [hashtable] $param6 = @{foo = 'var'}) {

}
```

You can use the [`ParseFile` Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.language.parser.parsefile?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0#system-management-automation-language-parser-parsefile(system-string-system-management-automation-language-token()@-system-management-automation-language-parseerror()@)) to get the AST, then you can use the [`.FindAll` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.language.ast.findall?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0) to filter for all [`FunctionDefinitionAst`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.language.functiondefinitionast?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0) and subsequently find all parameters filtering for  all [`ParameterAst`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.language.parameterast?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0).

```bash
using namespace System.Management.Automation.Language

$ast = [Parser]::ParseFile('path\to\myScript.ps1', [ref] $null, [ref] $null)
$ast.FindAll({ $args[0] -is [FunctionDefinitionAst] }, $true) | ForEach-Object {
    $out = [ordered]@{ Function = $_.Name }
    $_.FindAll({ $args[0] -is [ParameterAst] }, $true) | ForEach-Object {
        $out['ParameterName'] = $_.Name.VariablePath
        $out['Type']          = $_.StaticType
        $out['DefaultValue']  = $_.DefaultValue
        [pscustomobject] $out
    }
} | Format-Table
```

Above code would result in the following for `myScript.ps1`:

```
Function     ParameterName Type                                         DefaultValue
--------     ------------- ----                                         ------------
ExampleFunc  param1        System.Int32                                 123
ExampleFunc  param2        System.String
ExampleFunc2 param3        System.Object
ExampleFunc2 param4        System.Management.Automation.SwitchParameter
ExampleFunc3 param5        System.Object
ExampleFunc3 param6        System.Collections.Hashtable                 @{foo = 'var'}
```

The same could be accomplished using [`Get-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/get-command?view=powershell-7.2):

```bash
(Get-Command 'fullpath\to\myScript.ps1').ScriptBlock.Ast.FindAll({
    ... same syntax as before ... }, $true # or $false for non-recursive search
)
```

Comment: Santiago. That's perfect. I've confirmed that I can use that to get a list of all of the parameters (or anything) in the script. Really impressive. I do need to use PowerShell 7.0 rather than the 5.1 I was getting in a couple places, but that's achievable.

Comment: @ScottForsyth I'm glad this was helpful, i added a minimal example that targets functions in a script specifically, tho, you can find everything by traversing the AST. I didn't want to go too much into detail because it's a quite complex topic and I personally would not consider myself knowledgeable enough

Comment: Santiago (or anyone else), I got back to working on this and discovered that PowerShell 7 supports the optional parameters already. It doesn't fail if a parameter is passed in that isn't implemented in the script.

That wasn't the case in PowerShell 5.1 where it threw an exception. After upgrading all DevOps agents to use PowerSehll 7, it 'just worked'. This made it easier and I didn't have to use the AST after all (although it was helpful to be aware of AST)

Comment: @ScottForsyth I'm not aware of such thing, I believe you're referring to a script or function that is not implementing `cmdletbinding`, in which case if you pass parameters that do not exists in the target function it would be ignored instead of getting an exception (which applies for both WinPS and PS Core). A simple example `function test {param($s, $d) $s, $d}; test -s asd -d zxc -x asd` (`-x` is a not existing parameter yet it would be ignored since the function is not an advanced one)

Comment: You're right, something else is in play. It's not the PS 5.1 and 7.2 difference after all. I can also see it by testing "get-childitem -abc". In my console windows, those fail with unknown parameters. However, from the VS Code terminal window (also 7.2.3), it doesn't fail. Fortunately, it appears that the DevOps agent doesn't complain either. I have a solution now, but I'm not sure what setting toggles that difference.