# How to get all functions defined in a .ps1 file?

Tags: powershell

I have some functions defined in a .ps1 file, which I can import them by a dot operator (`. .\script.ps1`).  After that, I can use these functions in my powershell terminal. If it's a module, I could use the `gcm -module ...` command to get all commands from the module. But here it's a file, not a module. Is there a way for me to list all functions defined in the file? Like `gcm -file "script.ps1"`.

Comment: You want to load them into your session or just list their names?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon Load into my session and check their names for reference purpose.

Comment: If you want to inspect the functions in the file __before or without dot sourcing it__, you can use the `Parser` class to inspect the AST. One example in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71994652/15339544).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve this indirectly, by **querying the `.File` property of the `.ScriptBlock` property of function objects ([`System.Management.Automation.FunctionInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.FunctionInfo))**:

- To match by script file *name* only:

  ```bash
  Get-Command -Type Function | 
    Where-Object { $_.ScriptBlock.File -like '*[\/]script.ps1' } | 
    ForEach-Object Name
  ```
- **To avoid ambiguity, you should match against the *full* script path**, not just the file name, e.g.:

  ```bash
  Get-Command -Type Function | 
    Where-Object { $_.ScriptBlock.File -eq 'C:\path\to\script.ps1' } | 
    ForEach-Object Name
  ```

  - Note that `.File` always reports the path as a *file-system-native* one, even if you dot-sourced the script via a PowerShell-only drive. When in doubt, use `Convert-Path` on a path in order to convert it to a file-system-native one.

---

[Santiago Squarzon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15339544/santiago-squarzon) points to an interesting **variation** of your task: **Get the list of all functions directly from a script file (`.ps1`)**, irrespective of whether the script has been dot-sourced or not (i.e., irrespective of whether the functions have (already) been *defined* in the session):

```bash
# Returns the names of all functions defined in specified script
(Get-Command 'C:\path\to\script.ps1').ScriptBlock.Ast.FindAll(
  { $args[0] -is [System.Management.Automation.Language.FunctionDefinitionAst] },
  $false # parameter `searchNestedScriptBlocks`
).Name
```

See also:

- [`System.Management.Automation.Language.Ast`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.Language.Ast), the class that the script's [AST (abstract syntax tree)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree), reported in `.ScriptBlock.Ast`, is an instance of.
- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71994652/15339544) by Santiago, which shows more advanced techniques for reflecting on a script's functions (examining their parameters).

Answer (score 1):

A more advanced use case is when you want to find a Command (i.e function with `CmdLetBinding`) defined in the current script, by name:

```
# eg. C:\Users\username\scriptName.ps1
$MyScriptPath = $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition.ToString()

# Filter the commands available in the current context.
$Cmd = Get-Command -Type Function |
    Where-Object { $_.ScriptBlock.Ast.Body.ParamBlock.Attributes.TypeName.Name -eq 'CmdLetBinding' } |
        Where-Object { $_.ScriptBlock.File -eq $MyScriptPath } |
            Where-Object { $_.Name -eq $CommandName }
```

This should give you a list of `FunctionInfo` objects that have all the metadata about the commands, including the `ScriptBlock`. After finding/validating, you can execute the command simply using `& $CommandName`